# Git: Prevent a local and remote copy of a file from overwriting each other

Tags: git, github

I have a project on GitHub. There is a config file P in my project required by one of the components in the project with a specific name and location that cannot be changed.

In order to run the JUnit tests locally on my computer, and also by some remote server, we need two different contents and configurations in P. The problem is that since P, is in the repository, Git pull and push commands overwrite P on the server or on my computer.

I want to find a solution to prevent Git pulls and pushes to overwrite P. In other words, I am looking for a solution that tells Git that it is okay if a file has a different content remotely and locally. Is there any solution for this?

(This information may not be relevant, but it is an Android project and the component that needs P is Roboelectric. The remote server that runs the JUnit tests is Travis).

Answer (score 0):

Your only alternative would be to REMOVE that file from Source Control.

`git rm --cached P` would tell git to **stop** tracking it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If it is already in the server and you want to make git "forget" about the file, you need to use the `.gitignore` (that's why it's there!).

To stop tracking a file use the command:

`git rm --cached <file>`

This removal will happen in the next commit you do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed your instruction and placed P in my .gitignore and also called "git rm --cached P". However, and when I try to commit my changes now, git is trying to delete the remote copy as well which is not desired. I want to keep the remote copy of P unchanged.

Comment: After some research found that this will indeed delete the file on your remotes, check out this gist that gives you the answer: https://gist.github.com/canton7/1423106 if this works for you tell me to edit the answer.